# python Стек напишите и объясните

Tags: python, алгоритм, инспекция-кода

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Напишите программу, которая проверяет правильность скобочного выражения с четырьмя видами скобок: (), [], {} и <>.

```
input = '*+/=?^_`{|}~-+@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])'
brackets = [('(', ')'), ('[', ']'), ('{', '}')]
def check(input, brackets):
    stack = []
    for ch in input:
        for br in brackets:
            if br[0] == ch:
                stack.append(ch)
                break
            elif br[1] == ch:
                if stack and br[0] == stack.pop():
                    break
                else:
                    return False
print(check(input, brackets))
```

Comment: Як вы барин, может за вас еще и лабораторную сдать?

Comment: ахах было бы не плохо)

Comment: я просто не понимаю, поэтому прошу помочь)

Comment: Объясните хотя бы, что за скобочные выражения?  Примеры входных/выходных данных.  Ваши попытки решить, или хотя бы домыслы.

Comment: Почему не получается где ошибка?

Comment: "Скобочное выражение" в переменной input?  Это регулярное выражение, что-ли?

Comment: И, пожалуйста, выложите код в виде текста, а не скриншота.

Comment: Если Вам подошёл ответ, [отметьте его как правильный](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 2):

В целом Ваш алгоритм работает правильно, добавил лишь пару штрихов, чтобы функция возвращала `True` когда открытые скобки соответствуют закрытым, и `False` - когда нет.

И совет - не используйте в качестве имён переменных и функций зарезервированные имена, в данном случае - `input`.

```
in_str_correct_0 = '*+/=?^_`{|}~-+@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])';
in_str_correct_1 = 'sfadsfdsgafsdf';
in_str_incorrect_0 = '[';
in_str_incorrect_1 = '[()[]{}]{[]';

brackets = [('(', ')'), ('[', ']'), ('{', '}'), ('<', '>')];

def check(in_str, brackets):
    stack = []
    for ch in in_str:
        for br in brackets:
            if br[0] == ch:
                stack.append(ch)
                break
            elif br[1] == ch:
                if stack and br[0] == stack.pop():
                    break
                else:
                    return False

    if ( len(stack) == 0 ):
        return True;
    else:
        return False;


print(check(in_str_correct_0, brackets));
print(check(in_str_correct_1, brackets));
print(check(in_str_incorrect_0, brackets));
print(check(in_str_incorrect_1, brackets));
```

Вывод:

```
True                                                                                                                                 
True                                                                                                                                 
False                                                                                                                                
False
```

Comment: Я питон не знаю, потому могу ошибаться, но разве вот это `for br in brackets:` не линейный поиск? Наверное, лучше было бы хранить `brackets` как хешсет, а не массив?